# function in a stateless componenet

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const StatelessComp = props => {

    const anotherFunction = () => (
       return <span><Button onClick={()=>props.incomingFunction}>Reset</Button></span>
    )

    return (
        <TableHeaderColumn
                    className="tableHeader"
                    dataFortmat={anotherFunction}
                >Restore</TableHeaderColumn>
};
```

why is it giving me error when i `return` something in `anotherFunction`. Id like to display a `Restore` button on a column.

Comment: What is the error? And what does `TableHeaderColumn` expect in the `dataFortmat` prop?

Answer (score 1):

It's an arrow function with a concise body. It must contain an expression, not any statements like `return`. You should write

```
const anotherFunction = () => (
  <span><Button onClick={()=>props.incomingFunction}>Reset</Button></span>
);
```

or

```
const anotherFunction = () => {
  return (
    <span><Button onClick={()=>props.incomingFunction}>Reset</Button></span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Good point. This was more of a JavaScript ES6 question, nothing to do with React.